# Batch edit the file creation date

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Someone set the wrong date in the camera settings and now has several hundred pictures with 2013 as the year. Is there a way to batch-edit the creation date by decreasing the year by 1?

Thanks in advance

Comment: A google search gives this result: http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/powershell/changing-folder-creation-date/

Comment: Are you referring to the actual *file* creation date, or the photo metadata?

Comment: If this is a one shot you better use an existing tool than rolling your own (unless you want to learn something in the process). Here is one http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/

Comment: is that the file creation date or the last modification date? I'd rather fix the modification date and not the file creation date. The file creation date is updated everytime you copy the file to another place so it is pretty useless. The file modification date is preserved on copy.

Comment: Another tool: http://www.exiv2.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://chrisjwarwick.wordpress.com/2011/11/08/modify-date-taken-values-on-photos-with-powershell-the-update-exifdatetaken-script-cmdlet/) you can find 2 powershell script to `get` & `set` `Exif Date Taken` of your photos.

Read carefully what Chris wrote in his blog.

I've used this script for the same your problem on some `jpeg` before buying **LightRoom** that do EXIF editing really easy.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could also use a ComObject in PowerShell [Wia.ImageFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms630506%28VS.85%29.aspx) to manipulate the information. PowerShell Team wrote a blog post on it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/03/31/image-manipulation-in-powershell.aspx). They provided a module that you might be able to use. I loaded a file and found the DateTaken in the value of "DateTime" under the Properties property of the $image variable, if done as the blog post showed an example of.

I think you could also do this in the GUI of Windows Explorer. I took two files I had taken with a Canon and selected both of them and went into Properties. Under the Details tab I just changed the year value. The month, day, and time staid the same. I did this on two files and it worked, although if you are talking about hundreds not sure how that would perform.
[image]